# Mapbox pulsingDot's with individual background colors

Tags: canvas, mapbox

Based on this famous example I would like to be able to add multiple Dots (POI's) with individual background colors:
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-image-animated/

So what I did so far is to add a `bgcolor` variable at the top which is used to set up `context.fillStyle = bgcolor;`

```js
    pulsingDot = {
    
    width: size,
    height: size,
    bgcolor: '#88888880',
    data: new Uint8Array(size * size * 4),
    
    // When the layer is added to the map,
    // get the rendering context for the map canvas.
    onAdd: function () {
      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = this.width;
      canvas.height = this.height;
      this.context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    },
    
    // Call once before every frame where the icon will be used.
    render: function () {
      const duration = 2000;
      const t = (performance.now() % duration) / duration;
      
      const radius = (size / 2) * 0.3;
      const outerRadius = (size / 2) * 0.7 * t + radius;
      const context = this.context;
      
      context.shadowBlur = 20;
      context.shadowColor = "#80808080";
    
      // Draw the outer circle.
      context.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(
        this.width / 2,
        this.height / 2,
        outerRadius,
        0,
        Math.PI * 2
      );
      context.fillStyle = `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${0.2 * (1 - t)})`;
      context.fill();
      
      // Draw the inner circle.
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(
        this.width / 2,
        this.height / 2,
        radius,
        0,
        Math.PI * 2
      );
      context.fillStyle = this.bgcolor;
      context.fill();
      
      // Update this image's data with data from the canvas.
      this.data = context.getImageData(
        0,
        0,
        this.width,
        this.height
      ).data;
      
      // Continuously repaint the map, resulting
      // in the smooth animation of the dot.
      map.triggerRepaint();
      
      // Return `true` to let the map know that the image was updated.
      return true;
    }
    };
```

Then I add the dot's to mapbox like this:

```js
    dot_red = pulsingDot;
    dot_red.bgcolor = '#FF0000';
    map.addImage(image_red, dot_red, { pixelRatio: 2 });
    ...
    
    dot_green = pulsingDot;
    dot_green.bgcolor = '#00FF00';
    map.addImage(image_green, dot_green, { pixelRatio: 2 });
    ...
```

But when I do it like this all dot's get the same color. This is just an example, in general I would like to be able to add any parameter to pulsingDot and draw individual pulsing dots on the map (color, blinking speed, size and so on...).

Thanks & best Regards,
Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that finally worded for me was to use `Object.assign()`. It may not be the most elegant way so better solutions are still welcome!

```js
    dot_red = Object.assign({}, pulsingDot);
    dot_red.bgcolor = '#FF0000';
    map.addImage(image_red, dot_red, { pixelRatio: 2 });
    
    dot_green = Object.assign({}, pulsingDot);
    dot_green.bgcolor = '#00FF00';
    map.addImage(image_green, dot_green, { pixelRatio: 2 });
```

Comment: Thank you! You answered a question I was about to spend hours trying to figure out. Wish there was a more elegant way to do this, but it's javascript syntax that I'm pretty unfamiliar with and just can't figure out a way to structure the thing where I can pass parameters into the object (with a single instance of the object).